# Dynamic Image in Android? (Beginner Question)

Tags: android, graphics

I would like to display a .png file from the R.drawable to the screen.  Eventually I would like this image to be dynamic, meaning that it's position can move based on specified x,y coordinates.

I have looked into it but I am confused by the many options.  Here are most of my questions:

What is the best data type/object to use for the situation?
What is the best way to instatiate the image?
Does it need to be a Drawable?
Does the Drawable then need its own View?
To display it, do I just add the new View to the main view?

I have experience with numerical method algorithms, but this is my first venture into graphics and I'm a bit overwhelmed, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Edit - For the movement of the image, it will be moving around a lot, eventually as a user controlled movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, there are many ways to do this. The "best" way depends on lots of things. If you want something like a ball bouncing around inside an area on the screen, the best approach might be to create a custom View and draw your .png in the onDraw() method at whatever coordinates you want. You can load your .png as a Bitmap using `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()`.

Comment: So, just to figure out the order, it would go png gets loaded as a Bitmap with BitmapFactory, then Bitmap gets loaded into a custom view with View.onDraw() override, then to display it just add it to the main view with one of main's methods.  Am I understanding your suggestion right?

Comment: I think you have the idea, although I'd phrase it differently. Define a custom View and in its constructor load the bitmap. It might be useful to construct a Paint object as well, for later use in onDraw.) In its onDraw method (which gets passed a Canvas), use the drawBitmap method of Canvas to draw the bitmap where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Ted said, if you want the image to later move around, you may want to draw it to a canvas. There are several useful draw methods for Canvas. SurfaceView is another option as well.

```
pic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), img);

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(pic, x, y, null);
    //canvas.drawRect(x, y, right, bottom, null);
}
```